# When should "podman system migrate" be run?

Tags: podman

It seems [`podman system migrate`](https://github.com/containers/libpod/blob/master/docs/podman-system-migrate.1.md) is sometimes needed to upgrade
the file formats or the directory structure of the files stored by podman. (I assume the changes happen under the directory ~/.local/share/containers/)

Is there a command that can tell me whether running `podman system migrate` is necessary?

This question is about rootless use of podman (i.e. running podman as a normal user).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as rootless user, you need to run it every time the user namespace configuration is changed (e.g. you add more ids to `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`) and you want podman to recreate the user namespace